# imported json data assigning to existing state not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The json file is imported in the code and I am trying to assign existing json data to state in render function but it is not working
            jsondata.json

```
import students1 from '../JsonData/jsondata'

class PostList extends Component {
   constructor(pops) {
    super()
     this.state = { 
      students:
     [{ id: 1, name: 'rahul', Agee: 21 ,dept:'IT'},
    { id: 2, name: 'shiva', Agee: 19 ,dept:'CIVIL'},
       { id: 4, name: 'Asad', Agee: 25,dept:'ELECT'}
       ] }
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
 }

render() {
this.setState(
    {students: this.state.students.concat(JSON.parse(students1))})
}}
```

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(students1))) its creating same data structure like student specified in state....i used both parse and stringfy and just parse but still not able to push data to state

Comment: **Do not call `this.setState` inside of `render`**. This will cause your component to keep re-rendering infinitely. If you want to assign initial state to your component, do it in the `constructor`. Also, get rid of `this.setState = this.setState.bind(this)` from the constructor - this is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what i want is add more imported json data to existing state

Answer (score 0):

Your code is poorly formatted and hard to read.
Manipulate your data outside of the render function (in the constructor in your case).

The setState trigger the render (and the render trigger the setState in your case). You have a loop here.

remove this line :

```
this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
```

This is from React and properly binded already.

Comment: Thank you for the info. My que is i have json file that i imported in my component now i have existing state to which i want to add data imported from json file